# Rails 4 Mounted Engine Rspec Url adding params twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, rails-engines

I have a Rails 4 mounted engine `MyEngine`

Inside a `lib` module I'm using the `url_helper` to find a route.

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.url_helpers.send("test_controller_url",{:id => 1, :lang => I18n.locale})
```

And I have configured `rspec` with the `default_url_options` in `spec/spec_helper.rb` like this.

```
class ActionView::TestCase::TestController
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :params => { :lang => I18n.default_locale }, :host => "test.host" }.merge options
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :params => { :lang => I18n.default_locale }, :host => "test.host" }.merge options
  end
end
```

The resultant `url` I'm expecting from the call is:

```
http://test.host/controller/1/test?lang=en
```

But I'm getting the `url`:

```
http://test.host/?lang=en/controller/1/test?lang=en
```

I did some debugging into `actionpack/action_dispatch/http/url.rb` in `actionpack-4.0.1` of `rails`.

The options that come to the `url_for` method are:

```
{
  :params=>{:lang=>:en}, 
  :host=>"test.host", 
  :use_route=>"my_engine", 
  :only_path=>true, 
  :lang => :en, 
  :path=>"/", 
  :script_name=>nil, 
  :user=>nil, 
  :password=>nil
}
```

and

```
{
  :params=>{:lang=>:en}, 
  :host=>"test.host", 
  :action=>"test", 
  :controller=>"my_engine/controller", 
  :use_route=>"test_controller", 
  :only_path=>false, 
  :id=>1, 
  :path=>"/controller/1/test", 
  :script_name=>"/?lang=en", 
  :user=>nil, 
  :password=>nil
}
```

And in the `dummy` rails application inside `spec/dummy/config/routes.rb` I've mounted the `engine` with:

```
mount MyEngine::Engine, :at => "/"
```

It seems to produce the malformed `url` only with `rspec` and not even with `rails console`

I also noticed that there are two calls being made to `url_for`, one for the `engine` and one for the actual `path`.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it a configuration thing or is there an actual bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `:params` and `:lang` from the `default_url_options` did the trick.